# At what temp does mayo and salad dressings spoil?

Tags: food-safety

My compressor is going out and milk spoils.  The repair man says it will take a week to 10 days to get a new one.  It is still cool in there but not cold.  I just opened a new jar of mayo and some salad dressings. I want to be safe but no wasteful.

Comment: ...get a cooler and some ice?

Comment: ...cook the mayonnaise to make a delicious mayonnaise chocolate cake. I don't have a solution for the dressing though. http://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/chocolate-mayonnaise-cake

Comment: Hello Beverly, we only discuss strict food safety here. This means that we don't make guesses about temperatures at which something will spoil, which are 1) unreliable, and 2) not much related to the safe-unsafe distinction. If you want to go by "spoiled" then you have to trust your nose. If you want to go by "safe", see the linked question, and read https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info.

Answer (score -2):

I'd throw it out (and everything else that is in the fridge), especially if you know your fridge will be out for days.

Better be safe and loose a few $ than risk of being sick.

"...If you lose electricity, keep refrigerator and freezer doors closed as much as possible. Your refrigerator will keep food cold for about four hours if it's unopened. A full freezer will keep an adequate temperature for about 48 hours if the door remains closed..."

https://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ConsumerUpdates/ucm093704.htm